# TypeError: date is not a function

Tags: react-native

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(1598051730000));
const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
setDate(currentDate);
};

const showMode = (currentMode) => {
setShow(true);
setMode(currentMode);
};

const showDatepicker = () => {
showMode('date');
};

<DateTimePicker
      testID="dateTimePicker"
      display="default"
      mode={mode}
      value={date}
      onChange={(date) => {
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        if (date) {
          date(new Date(date));
        }
      }}
      onChangeText={(val) => set_birthdate(val)}
    />
```

> TypeError: date is not a function. (In 'date(new Date(date))', 'date' is an instance of Object)

Can someone help me with this?

i'm adding the full code

Comment: Can you share your state, maybe you should use setDate(new Date(date)); if you are using useState hook and having a setter

Comment: `date` is the value your callback gets passed as an argument. So what would you expect `date(new Date(date))` to do? If there is really some function `date()` out there, you must rename your argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setDate(new Date(date))` instead of `date(new Date(date));` also please rename your arg for avoiding confusion, try below code

```
onChange={(newDate) => {
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    newDate && setDate(new Date(newDate));
}}
```